# Having trouble with a SMC reset

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, power-management

I'm having trouble with my built in iSight and I'm trying to reset the SMC. My MBP has a non-removable SMC, so the instructions ask me to press CMD-SHIFT-ALT-POWER at the same time, release it at the same time and then press the power button to power on the machine.

Trouble is that, the machine power ons when I press CMD-SHIFT-ALT-POWER and I dont think that resets the SMC. What should I be doing to correct this?

Comment: You have to take out the battery when doing this. Which MacBook do you have?

Comment: MacBook Pro 13-inch Retina

Comment: Strange, according to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dFCF86GOFRI your procedure sounds correct.

Answer (score 1):

That is the incorrect key combination. You are pressing <kbd>Command</kbd> instead of <kbd>Control</kbd>.

To [reset the SMC on portables with a builtin battery](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964), press (left side):

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Power Button</kbd>

Subsequently, release them at the same time. Then power on your computer.